# What are these sandwiches?

Tags: riddle

Tell me what I am talking about

> Fifty six sandwiches, middle portion pure
>
> All different but same, that we are sure.

HINT

> I am metallic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My two bits is these sandwiches are

> US Quarter coins

Fifty six sandwiches, middle portion pure

> There are [50 State quarters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_State_Quarters) and [6 from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_and_United_States_Territories_Quarters) from DC and the five territories Puerto Rico, Guam, United States Virgin Islands, American Samoa, the Northern Mariana Islands so altogether 56.
>
>  These [US quarters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_(United_States_coin)) are a sandwich of cupronickel (75% Cu : 25% Ni) with a core of pure copper.

All different but same, that we are sure.

> They all have different reverse designs, are equivalent to 25 cents, and are metallic.

Update:

> During 2010 - 2021 the [America the Beautiful](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_the_Beautiful_Quarters) Quarters program is releasing 56 coins.

Comment: "My two bits," was that an intentional pun? Because that works too well 

Comment: Finally!  US Quarters are very unique. They are made by cladding Cu/Ni strips and a copper strip. This was done to change the magnetic properties which were designed into the Vending and Telephone machines.

Answer (score 2):

you are talking about

> Genders. Facebook allows 56 different settings for your preferred gender.

Fifty six sandwiches, middle portion pure

> We all are just flesh sandwiches housed by skin, our insides or 'middle portion' is our humanity

All different but same, that we are sure

> each gender has its own traits, but we are all human, therefore, all the same.

Comment: Facebook allows 3 or infinite genders - Male, Female and Custom.  There's no way to get 56 out of that.

Comment: I think he's referring to this : http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/02/21/gender_facebook_now_has_56_categories_to_choose_from_including_cisgender.html

Comment: @ChrisCudmore http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2014/02/13/facebook_custom_gender_options_here_are_all_56_custom_options.html

Comment: Jason. Guess my answer is different and may be very direct.

Comment: Go play with the gender settings on facebook.   There are three choices

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Once you select 'custom' there are many genders that you can actually choose, as soon as you start typing you can see which genders are available to choose. Apparently FB users in the UK can choose from 71 genders, I don't know how many there are in total.

Comment: I get a free form text entry box.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore You should get recommendations as soon as you start typing, I've only tested it in Chrome. It might not work on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible answer:

> **[Midway Atoll, Hawaii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_Atoll)**

---

*Fifty six*

> Midway was claimed for the United States under the Guano Islands Act of 18**56**
>  (This one is a bit of a stretch perhaps)

*sandwiches*

> The island is part of the Hawaiian Islands, formerly known to Europeans and Americans as the **Sandwich Islands**.

*middle portion*

> The island is known as **Midway (Middle)** and it is roughly equidistant between North America and Asia.

*pure*

> Midway is the the only island in the Hawaiian archipelago that is not part of the state of Hawaii.

*All different but same, that we are sure.*

> All of the **Sandwich** islands are different but still part of the same state (Hawaii)

Comment: 56 is a key number Ambo100 that stands on its own

Comment: @DEEM 56 is litterally 'key number' 8. There are 8 Hawaiian islands. Although you might be trying to say that's just coincidence and it has no relation to Hawaii...